# Sending IR code on LG G4

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, infrared, lg

I developed a remote control app for android phones, it works well on all phones that have an IR blaster except the LG G4.

The app does send a signal but it is very weak and short ranged in comparison to the LG Remote app.

I have been trying to change the duration pattern that I am sending and even if I send the exact same one that the LG app sends I still need to be super close to the TV for it to work (LG app works from a couple of meters).

This is the code that I am using to send the signals:

```
long wait = 200 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSentCodeTime);
Log.d(App.TAG, wait + " - wait");
if (wait < 0) wait = 0;
lastSentCodeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + wait + 200;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (ready && (mIR != null)) {
                    try {
                        mIR.sendIRPattern(irFreq, durationCode);
                        Log.d("infrared", "send Code");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Crashlytics.log("LG infrared failure: "+ e.getMessage());
                        restartLG();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}, wait);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        lgStopIR();
    }
}, wait + 200);
```

I tried looking everywhere but couldn't find anything.

Comment: LG has their own IR SDK - http://developer.lge.com/MOBILE_HELP/index.jsp?topic=%2Flge.mobilesdk.LGQRemote.api%2Flgqremotesdk.htm and I don't see any specification in the Android Compatibility Definition Document that they MUST support it in a useful manner: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf

Comment: @MorrisonChang
I am using LG's IR SDK.. It works well on G2 and G3 phones, the problem is only on G4

Comment: @DaniG I'm not able to send IR commands on LG G3 and apparently, you are able to send IR commands. Would you be so kind to have a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483704/sending-infrared-commands-on-lg-g3-s